# What are the options that the web3.js solidity compiler passes to solc?

Tags: solidity, web3js, clients

I've been using the following command to compile my contracts from CLI:

```
solc ballot.sol --combined-json abi,asm,bin,interface > ballot.json
```

However, the `ballot.json` file has a completely different structure from the object generated by the:

```
web3.eth.compile.solidity(<source code>)
```

How could I figure out what arguments are being passed to `solc` from inside the `web3.js` client

Answer (score 3):

web3 doesn't actually pass the compiler options.  web3 makes a json rpc call.  You can see the details of that here:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_compilesolidity

In the pyethereum client it uses the following params to solc:

`--add-std --optimize --combined-json abi,bin,devdoc,userdoc`

Depending on the client you are using, you may have to dig through the source code

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but when you run `geth console`, you are left with a node REPL running web3.js, aren't you? If so, why would you have an option to pass the `solc` binary path to `geth` in order to have your code compiled if you don't use it directly?